# How to dynamically add and set child data from ArrayList on click of Group of Expandable Listview?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am having arraylist which is having data from WebService.
Now I want to add this data on particular group click of Expandable listview.

Comment: yes you can add it..make baseAdapter or ArrayAdapter and when you get new object or data then set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: But I am using BaseExpandableListAdapter to set group data. And after Setting all group dat when user clik on particular group I want to add child data.

Comment: then also do same expadableadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Once data is changed you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to the adapter. 
But, while data is been added to the list , if you are using expandableList, you will face a runtime exception saying, adapter data is changed and it's not notified. So, add all the data togerther to adpater and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to the adapter.

Comment: Thanx.. but my problem is for first time I am not having any child data. On particular group click I'm getting child data and that child data I want to set on that particular group.